# RxDB check if a local database exists

Tags: javascript, rxdb

How can I find out whether the local db (indexedDB) with a given name already exists?

```
const db = await createRxDatabase({
  name: 'heroesdb',
  storage: getRxStoragePouch('idb'),
});
```

This approach, which is provided by [the docs](https://rxdb.info/rx-database.html#importdump), just silently create a new db as long as there is no db with with the name `heroesdb`.

What is the best workaround to achieve that?

Comment: Did you find the solution to this problem?

Comment: @SathishkumarRakkiyasamy No, to my knowledge, it hasn't been implemented as yet